# Mirth Database Reader channel automatically reruns CRON query when you delete the message history?

Tags: mirth, defects

Is this a defect?  "Remove all messages" causes this channel type to automatically reprocess?

Create a channel with:

- Database Reader Source that
  -- runs on a CRON (0 5 * * * ? for example)
  -- does not use Javascript (uses the SQL text block)
  -- does not aggregate results
  -- does not cache results
- File Writer Destination
  -- append to file
  -- write the SELECT columns out to the file

Then run the channel.  After it runs and you write numerous rows to the output file,
go into the Dashboard and try to "REMOVEALL" messages.  It cleared the messages, but goes right back into polling the DB and rerunning the query regrardless what the Source Cron was set to.

This creates duplicates in the output file if we clear the dashboard message history.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly edit the channel to be able to flag records that have already been read in the database reader source connector. You can achieve this by adding a state flag (i.e is_sent column) to the source table. Essentially, setting a default value of 0 then toggling to 1 once pulled by Mirth connect.